# Wordpress 5.8 update problem custom theme styles are overridden by core styles common.min.css

Tags: theme-development, css, updates

After the automatic **update to wordpress 5.8** today one of my custom themes **displayed wrong styling in the frontend** for custom webfonts, colors, font-sizes and other styles. After a quick check in the dev tools I realized that this is caused by `common.min.css` an automatically generated collection of core styles that hasn't been present in Wordpress 5.7.2 (I quickly reverted the live site from 5.8 to 5.7.2). On localhost I kept the updated (5.8) version to find a solution for the problem. If I deactivate `common.min.css` in the browser's dev tools everything looks fine again.

Is there a way to deregister this core style on frontend? I have tried to get my grips on deactivating unnecessary styles for hours and days in the past but haven't been successful so far – to be honest.

I have found some possibly related information in this recent **wordpress.org blog post**:
https://make.wordpress.org/core/2021/07/01/block-styles-loading-enhancements-in-wordpress-5-8/#respond but I am not 100 % sure if this relates to my problem and even if so I haven't found a solution in the post.

Ari mentions in the post that block styles (which I suppose are combined into `common.min.css`) are loaded in the footer using `print_late_styles()` and that for classic, php-based themes (which my theme is – in contrast to the new block themes) this causes conflicts with the priority of the styles / stylesheets load order.

Any help or advise really appreciated as I need to find a quick solution (and maybe others are facing the same problem?)

Comment: Short update: after a conversation with Ari (Stathopoulos), the writer of the aforementioned blog post on wordpress.org my problem is unrelated to what is described in the post. The `common.min.css` I am refering to is an `wp-admin` css enqueued in the header and "leaking" into my frontend.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I think I am having the same issue now.

Comment: In the end it was a problem with my (self-written) custom blocks plugin. Wrapping the wp_enqueue_style function (to enqueue a custom editor.css file in the plugin's main PHP file) in an is_admin() check helped (it actually removed a ton of unnecessary css). If you have a similar setup you can get back to me if this isn't clear. Sorry for late answer.